# Why this code is working only with button type attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code where on click i am putting value in the input on the form.

This code here works fine.Will put value in the input.

```
    <form>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
        <input id="fname" type="text" id="fname"><br>
        <button id="btn" type="button">Submit</button>
    </form> 


var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var submitButton = document.getElementById("btn");

submitButton.addEventListener("click"  , function() {
    inputs[0].value = "fill in value in the input";
})
```

But my questions is why if i use

```
<button id="btn">Submit</button> 
OR
 <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
instead of
<button id="btn" type="button">Submit</button>
like in the first example
```

THEN the input will be not filled with the desired value from the JS.
When i click the button for one milisecond the input gets the value and then disappear.

Comment: It submits the form and that reloads the page.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your time.But by the input i have type="submit" then it submits the form,but by just button i dont have the submit thing,why it is submitting again ?

Comment: It defaults to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

You add the `click` EventListener for the element with ID `btn`. `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` does not have ID `btn`, and the eventListener is not applied to it. `<input id="btn" ...>` should work.

For `<button id="btn">Submit</button>`, it defaults to `type="submit"`, so the page is reloaded when you click it. You could use `e.preventDefault()` in the `click` handler to stop that if you wanted.

Comment: @Christina.It is typo.I edited with the id="btn".But with that it is not working also....